# What's the dumpbin equivalent to mono?

Tags: .net, mono

The windows utility of dumpbin can be used for digging into binary files for .NET exe/dll assemblies, as is explained in [this site](http://www.grimes.demon.co.uk/workshops/fusWSThree.htm).

dumpbin /clrheader lib.dll

```
Dump of file lib.dll
File Type: DLL
  clr Header:
    48 cb
  2.00 runtime version
  210C [ 374] RVA [size] of MetaData Directory
     9 flags
     0 entry point token
     0 [ 0] RVA [size] of Resources Directory
  2050 [ 80] RVA [size] of StrongNameSignature Directory
     0 [ 0] RVA [size] of CodeManagerTable Directory
     0 [ 0] RVA [size] of VTableFixups Directory
     0 [ 0] RVA [size] of ExportAddressTableJumps Directory
```

What would be the equivalent to this tool with mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We build a program named pedump that does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
monodis
```

may be able to give you some of this info: http://www.mono-project.com/Dis/Assembling_CIL_Code